# FBLoginView customise of UIAlertView Button?

Tags: ios, facebook, uialertview

I have a `UIAlertView` which contains two buttons, one for **twitter sharing**, another for **facebook**.
For twitter, I simply call a method, but for facebook it need `FBLoginView` to sign in.

I have customised `FBLoginView` before, as a `UIButton`, but here how can use `FBLoginView` on `UIAlertView` button.

Comment: Any solution for this issue ?